# using decorators to define models in PyMC

Tags: python, numpy, pymc, mcmc

below is one way to define two stochastic Bernoulli random variables, one depending on the other with decorators. the model is meant to be:

```
p(A) = 0.5
p(B=True|A=True) = 0.75
p(B=True|A=False) = 0.05
```

using decorators in PyMC it is:

```
import pymc
from pymc import DiscreteUniform, Exponential, deterministic, Poisson, Uniform
import numpy as np

def make_model():
    @pymc.stochastic(dtype=bool)
    def A(value=False):
        def logp(value):
            return pymc.bernoulli_like(value, 0.5)

        def random():
            return bool(np.random.binomial(1, 10**logp(value)))


    @pymc.stochastic(dtype=bool)
    def B(value=False, A=False):
        def logp(value, A):
            if A:
                logp = pymc.bernoulli_like(value, 0.75)
            else:
                logp = pymc.bernoulli_like(value, 0.05)
            return logp

        def random(A):
            return bool(np.random.binomial(1, 10**logp(True, A)))

    return locals()

test = pymc.Model(make_model())
```

is this the most correct and compact way to do it? could some code be saved by defining the nodes explicitly as `pymc.Bernoulli` variables, rather than with the `stochastic` decorator?

the above code seems redundant having to always define how to sample from a bernoulli RV, but maybe this is unavoidable?

finally is it necessary to invoke sampling functions from `numpy` like `np.random.binomial` or are there sampling functions in PyMC?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that this is correct.  For example, if I sample from your model with the following code, I find the mean of the samples for `A` is not 0.5:

```
In [20]: pymc.MCMC(test).sample(10000)
 [-----------------100%-----------------] 10000 of 10000 complete in 0.6 sec
In [22]: test.A.trace().mean()
Out[22]:
0.19670000000000001
```

Here is a compact way to achieve your model:

```
import pymc as pm

def make_model():
    A = pm.Bernoulli('A', .5)
    B_given_A_true = pm.Bernoulli('B_given_A_true', .75)
    B_given_A_false = pm.Bernoulli('B_given_A_false', .05)

    @deterministic
    def B(A=A, B_given_A_true=B_given_A_true,
          B_given_A_false=B_given_A_false):
        if A:
            return B_given_A_true
        else:
            return B_given_A_false

    return locals()

test = pymc.Model(make_model())
```

Comment: why isn't B a stochastic node if its value is determined by a stochastic node A?

Comment: This language is confusing, `B` is deterministic because it is a deterministic function of stochastics.  See [here for more detail](http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/tutorial.html#two-types-of-variables).